# Java how to kill thread after a time out without checking interrupt

Tags: java, multithreading

How would you kill a thread in Java without manually checking `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`?

For example, how would you kill a thread like this after a time out:

```
new Thread(() -> {
  Result result = ExternalLibrary.performSomeReallyLongRunningTaskWithNoSideEffects();
  System.out.println(result);
}).start();
```

We cannot modify the external library code to add `isInterrupted` checks everywhere

Comment: You really can't ([safely](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--)). Java thread interruption is cooperative, so it relies on the thing being interrupted expecting and handling it.

Comment: The thing I am killing doesn't (shouldn't) have any side effects, so theoretically it should be ok.

Comment: @AndyTurner How about cancelling the future if there's any?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala `Future` is just an abstraction so you don't have to work with a thread directly, but ultimately, your work is done on a thread: as such, a Future can't do anything you can't do directly with a thread.

Comment: @AndyTurner Makes sense. As a bottom line your thread should be responsive to interruption. Isn't that so?

Comment: Re, "...doesn't (shouldn't) have any side effects."  In other words, you're saying it doesn't have any side effects _that you've thought of._ But consider that allocating an object from the heap _is_ a side effect. And, it may have others that you haven't thought of as well. If you don't know absolutely _everything_ that the thread does, then you can't be sure that killing it won't leave the rest of your program in a damaged, dysfunctional state.

Comment: Why can't you modify the external library code to add `isInterrupted` checks everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

For the timeout part, if you're open to using guava, [`SimpleTimeLimiter`](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter.html#callWithTimeout-java.util.concurrent.Callable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-boolean-) is a good option.

If you're long running thread does frequent IO, it may be as simple as using an interrupt (which for `SimpleTimeLimiter` you just need to invoke with `amInterruptible=true`), because IO operations will generally check the interrupt flag and throw an `InterruptedException` which you'd hope the third party code will propogate or use to terminate the operation.

If you're long running method doesn't check interrupts or ignores them, and modifying it is not an option, you may be stuck with `Thread.stop()`, which is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). If the long-running task is sufficiently isolated in it's operation, i.e. doesn't share variables with other running threads, and doesn't open any resources, it may be fine to just do that. But there is no way to be sure. I would definitely just try an interrupt first, it may just work.

Another alternative if the 3rd party code is truly opaque and unmodifiable, is convert it into it's own jar, and invoke it as an external process. That way the process can always be killed in isolation from your application.

In either the case of using `Thread.stop()` or a sending a kill signal to a separate process, you can execute these operations in response to the `UncheckedTimeoutException` thrown by `SimpleTimeLimiter#callWithTimeout(...)`

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed response. This external call doesn't have any side effects. I will update my question to reflect. Unfortunately the operation does no IO or any interrupt checking, so I guess I'm stuck with `Thread.stop()`